# CSS- How to make my elements responsively stack on top of each other for mobile/resized window use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on a visual calculator and have each segment organized into boxes. For the most part, everything looks okay when using a computer screen on a maximized window, but when I resize the window it condenses the boxes and makes everything illegible.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/mxLh1ayy/

```js
var  stocks= [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw","oz",115.4451262,3.293742347,72,4.85,5.65,0,2.142,19,20,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw","oz",115.4451262,3.293742347,50,5.65,2.83,0,1.109,19,18,0.0001275510204,0.375,0.75,22.15988372,0.3768292943,4  ],
  ["Chicken breast","oz",32.39053977,0.3923520408,34,6.38,0.74,0,0.16,13,21,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765300698,4  ],
  ["Chicken thighs/legs","oz",32.39053977,0.3923520408,125,2.72,12.54,0,3.431,14,30,0.01631172356,0.10625,0.2125,3.149953226,0.3765799405,4  ],
  ["Milk (whole)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.146234933,19,0.96,0.99,1.54,0.569,13,3,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Milk (2%)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.06133157758,15,1.06,0.58,1.54,0.363,16,2,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2417190282,8  ],
  ["Pizza (cheese)","slice",42,0.976332736,285,12.19,10.37,3.83,4.778,640,18,0.00001071428571,2.98828125,5.9765625,36.85985865,0.466697922,4  ],
  ["Ice Cream","cup",32.59312,0.6191784396,274.71344,4.6095984,14.4806576,27.9835216,8.94913952,107.09168,55.87392,0.000003990994286,1.11311325,2.2262265,13.73003196,2.889031735,1  ],
  ["Milk (skim)","fl oz",7.638924987,0.05948052127,10,1.03,0.02,1.54,0.017,13,1,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2415694159,8  ],
  ["Eggs (large)","each",43.13341461,0.5215603261,78,6.29,5.3,0.2,1.633,62,186,0.001666666667,0.265625,0.53125,3.713549,0.1305756192,1  ],
  ["Lamb","oz",78.125,4.010117347,80,4.69,6.64,0,2.889,17,21,0.03333333333,0.3125,0.625,2.274815967,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Cheese (hard)","slice (oz)",37.44571072,1.35234933,105,6.59,8.41,0.14,5.32,159,27,0.000003571428571,0.99609375,1.9921875,12.28661955,0.1303337926,1  ],
  ["Yogurt","oz",5.833333333,0.09395993304,17,0.98,0.92,1.32,0.595,13,4,3.571428571e-7,0.099609375,0.19921875,1.228661955,0.2229453548,6  ],
  ["Greek yogurt, vanilla (nonfat)","fl oz",15,0.08285194565,22,2.45,0.05,1.01,0.038,10,1,8.928571429e-7,0.3984375,0.796875,3.071654888,0.1965527472,6  ],
  ["Chocolate","oz",127.316,0.1863325866,151,2.16,8.39,14.57,5.238,22,7,7.142857143e-8,0.019921875,0.03984375,1.601963425,1.345070603,1.45  ],
  ["Cacao","oz",179.739,0.625,136,1.19,8.51,15.45,5.032,3,0,0,0,0,3.390577585,1.418619303,1.45  ],
  ["Salmon (farmed)","oz",0.498125,0.56925,59,5.79,3.8,0,0.864,17,16,0.004464285714,0.078125,0.15625,0.5593288054,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Tuna (canned in oil)","oz",0.498125,0.1197485281,56,8.26,2.33,0,0.435,118,5,0.000270197828,1.0625,2.125,0.5593288054,0.3817664985,4  ],
  ["Mayo","oz",14.41309121,0.1237135815,193,0.27,21.22,0.16,3.318,180,12,0.0004166666667,0.06640625,0.1328125,0.92838725,0.1330741748,0.5  ],
  ["Pulled Pork raw","oz",44.84498316,0.7763814526,53,4.94,3.5,0,1.232,17,18,0.0005208333333,0.21875,0.4375,1.592371177,0.3767295528,4  ],
  ["Butter (salted)","oz",41.58720633,0.5919085938,203,0.24,22.95,0.02,14.537,182,61,0.0000075,2.091796875,4.18359375,25.80190106,0.121322241,1  ],
  ["Soy Burger","oz",21.8,0.048125,50,4.44,1.78,0.3,0.408,161,1,0,0,0,2.314125,0.03342563782,4  ],
  ["Vegan Nuggets (soy)","oz",21.8,0.048125,52,4.88,1.63,0.65,0.325,172,0,0,0,0,2.314125,0.06360340429,4  ],
  ["Soymilk (original)","fl oz",2.319532348,0.02445449777,17,1,0.54,1.21,0.063,16,0,0,0,0,1.168382863,0.1032302684,8  ],
  ["Tofu","oz",25.25,0.09625,23,2.82,1.49,0.2,0.26,1,0,0,0,0,4.62825,0.01698083545,4  ],
  ["Tempeh","oz",12.383064,0.0230998152,54,5.74,3.06,0,0.719,3,0,0,0,0,1.110771114,0.0001496122504,4  ],
  ["Mixed Nuts","oz",18.72285536,0.18425,172,5.53,15.17,1.42,2.271,1,1,0,0,0,1.019662873,0.1202597201,1  ],
  ["Bread","slice",9.735884788,0.1530147137,79,3.09,1.31,1.66,0.202,137,0,0,0,0,0.5625,0.1473592997,2  ],
  ["Lentils","oz",30.3684714,0.07425,33,2.55,0.11,0.51,0.015,1,0,0,0,0,2.287814892,0.04322383072,7.1  ],
  ["Black Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,37,2.31,0.1,0.09,0.025,1,0,0,0,0,1.555714169,0.007668804863,7.1  ],
  ["Tomato Sauce","oz",3.13704,0.09375,11,0.47,0.06,1.37,0.008,57,0,0,0,0,0.4188459746,0.1188197409,8  ],
  ["Pinto Beans","oz",30.3684714,0.141625,40,2.55,0.18,0.09,0.038,0,0,0,0,0,0.9075003086,0.007618934113,7.1  ],
  ["French Fries","oz",2.9337142,0.0417335921,56,0.82,1.91,0.14,0.359,113,0,0,0,0,0.4200133922,0.01748707005,4  ],
  ["Peanut Butter","oz",36,0.2145,167,6.81,14.13,2.97,2.153,138,0,0,0,0,3.675378676,0.2583069893,1  ],
  ["Olive Oil","oz",21.77842536,0.2306145384,250,0,28.3,0,3.908,1,0,0,0,0,1.512500057,0.00004987075014,0.5  ],
  ["Banana","medium",6.440662244,0.1763699536,105,1.29,0.39,14.43,0.132,1,0,0,0,0,0.1768995697,1.221618974,1  ],
  ["Mixed vegetables","oz",2.41150377,0.125,18,0.81,0.04,0,0.009,10,0,0,0,0,3,0.0004987075014,4  ],
  ["Nutritional Yeast","g",0.08506329224,0.00706361088,3.9859577,0.5989518739,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5  ],
  ["Rice (white)","oz",25.46308329,0.34375,102,1.87,0.16,0,0.045,0,0,0,0,0,0.3995205753,0,2  ],
  ["Potatoes","oz",1.872285536,0.03575,16,0.73,0.03,0.2,0.007,3,0,0,0,0,0.06927480776,0.01708057695,5.3  ],
  ["Vegetable Oil","oz",17.70433203,0.125,205,0,23.8,0,19.937,0,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0,0.5  ],
  ["Wheat (flour)","cup",40.44136758,0.1235081329,408,13.56,1.88,0.36,0.276,4,0,0,0,0,1.598082301,0.03067521945,0.25  ],
  ["Margarine","oz",9.915624199,0.06125,102,0.28,11.32,0,2.048,222,0,0,0,0,5.300817694,0.01107130653,1  ],
  ["Corn Syrup","fl oz",11.15931776,0.01728062914,109,0,0,29.31,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.4854914297,2.481282747,1  ],
  ["Sugar","oz",11.23371322,0.01503093504,110,0,0,28.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.4340729937,2.395731504,1  ],
  ["Corn (grain)","oz",6.74022793,0.0104375,103,2.67,1.34,0.18,0.189,10,0,0,0,0,0.4549631935,0.01573657573,1  ],
  ["Soda","fl oz",10.64647779,0.02494335117,13,0,0.08,3.05,0,1,0,0,0,0,0.1939638153,0.2582470824,12  ]
]
function Stock (data) {
  return {
    name: data[0],
    servingUnit: data[1],
    water: [data[2], ''],
    carbon: [data[3], ''],
    calories: [data[4], ''],
    protein: [data[5], 'g'],
    fat: [data[6], 'g'],
    saturatedFat: [data[8], 'g'],
    sugar: [data[7], 'g'],
    sodium: [data[9], 'mg'],
    cholesterol: [data[10], 'mg'],
    lives: [data[11], ''],
    feed: [data[12], ''],
    meals: [data[13], ''],
    land : [data[14], ''],
    healthcare : [data[15], ''],
    unitsPerServing: data[data.length - 1]
  }
}

stocks = stocks.map(Stock)

var $selects = $('.selectStock')
var $quantity = $('#numberOfStocks')
var $comparisonResult = $('.comparison .result')

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).append(stocks.map(function(stock, i) {
    return new Option(stock.name, i)
  }))
})

function format(data, multiplier, digits,a) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString();
    console.log(data);
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="bad" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="good" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  return data.join(' ')
}

function format2(data, multiplier, digits,a) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString();
    console.log(data);
  if(a=="use" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="use" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="emit" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  else if (a=="emit" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="consumegood" && data[2]=="more"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-green'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  if(a=="consumegood" && data[2]=="less"){
  data[0]="<span class='color-red'>"+data[0]+"</span>"
  }
  return data.join(' ')
}
function stockFacts(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of carbon dioxide and methane equivalents <br>' +
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good","consumegood") + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad","consume") + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
    format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animal lives<br>' +
    format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' pounds of feed<br>' +
    format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' meals made from feed<br>' +
    format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land needed<br>' +
    "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save") + ' in projected healthcare costs<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFactsEnv(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of carbon dioxide and methane equivalents <br>' +
    format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land needed<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFactsHealth(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good","consumegood") + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad","consume") + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
    "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save") + ' in projected healthcare costs<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFactsSocial(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animal lives<br>' +
    format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' pounds of feed<br>' +
    format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' meals made from feed<br>'
  ]
}

function stockFacts2(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    "Use " + format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    "Emit " + format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of greenhouse gases<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.calories, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' calories<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.protein, quantity, 2,"good","consumegood") + ' of protein<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.fat, quantity, 3,"bad","consume") + ' of fat<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
   "Consume " +  format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sugar<br>' +
   "Consume " + format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of sodium<br>' +
    "Consume " + format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2,"bad","consume") + ' of cholesterol<br>' +
   "Require " +  format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animal lives to produce your food<br>' +
    "Require " + format(stock.feed, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' pounds of feed to produce your food<br>' +
    "Be able to produce " + format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' meals made from feed<br>' +
    "Require " + format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land to produce your food<br>' +
    "Cost the US healthcare system approximately " + "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save")
  ]
}

function stockFacts3(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    "Save " + format(stock.water, quantity, 2,"bad","use") + ' gallons of water<br>' +
    "Emit " + format(stock.carbon, quantity, 2,"bad","emit") + ' pounds of greenhouse gases<br>' +
   "Save " +  format(stock.lives, quantity, 5,"bad","save") + ' animals<br>' +
    "Feed " + format(stock.meals, quantity, 2,"bad","preserve") + ' people<br>' +
    "Require " + format(stock.land, quantity, 2,"bad","require") + ' square feet of land<br>' +
    "Cost the US healthcare system approximately " + "$"+format(stock.healthcare, quantity, 2,"bad","save")
  ]
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing
    
    $amount.text(' (' + amount + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity));
 $('#env_result').html(stockFactsEnv(diff, quantity));
  $('#health_result').html(stockFactsHealth(diff, quantity));
  $('#soc_result').html(stockFactsSocial(diff, quantity));
 $('#year_result').html(stockFacts2(diff, quantity*365));
  $('#US_result').html(stockFacts3(diff,quantity*323148587));
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}
```

```css
*{
    padding : 0;
      margin : 0;
}
body{
  height : 100vh;
  background-color: #F8F8FF;
}

.topnav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: #173;
    overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.box-1{
  height : 250px;
  width : 25%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display : inline-block;
  text-align : center;
  font-size : 1.5em;
}

.box{
  height : 250px;
  width : 20%;
  display : inline-block;
  text-align : center;
  font-size : 1.5em;
}

.box-2{
  height : 250px;
  width : 48%;
  display : inline-block;
    text-align : center;
  font-size : 1.5em;
}



@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .box{
    display : block;
    width : 100%;

  }
  
  .box-2{
    display : block;
    width : 100%;

  }
}

.color-red{
color:red;
background:transparent}
.color-green{
color:green;
background:transparent}


<style type="text/css">
 
#share-buttons img {
width: 35px;
padding: 5px;
border: 0;
box-shadow: 0;
display: inline;
background: transparent;
}
 
</style>

<style type="text/css">
/* Hide AddToAny vertical share bar when screen is less than 980 pixels wide */
@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {
    .a2a_floating_style.a2a_vertical_style { display: none; }
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#ingredient">Ingredient Calculator</a>
  <a href="#meal">Meal Calculator</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#sources">Sources</a></div>
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="box-1"> 
      <label>
    Servings:
        <br>
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>
        <br>
        <h3>The impact of swapping<span class="servingUnit"></span> of</h3>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <h3> 
          <br>
          with
        <span class="servingUnit"></span> of:</h3>
        <select class="selectStock">
          <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="box"><i class="fa fa-car" style="color:#A9A9A9"></i> Environmental Impact:</h2><div id="env_result"></div></div>
      <div class="box"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat" style="color:#FF69B4"></i> Health Impact:</h2><div id="health_result"></div></div>
      <div class="box"><img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8;base64,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" /> Social Impact:
      <div id="soc_result"></div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-container"> 
      <div class="box-2"><h3>
        If you made this switch every day for a year, you would:</h3>
<div id="year_result">
</div></div>
      <div class="box-2"> <h3>If everyone in America made this switch for just one meal, we would:</h3>
<div id="US_result">
</div></div>
    </div>
  </body>


<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_floating_style a2a_vertical_style" style="left:0px; top:150px;">
    <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
    <a class="a2a_button_pinterest"></a>
</div>

<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
```

As you can see, it is responsive when you resize, but instead of shortening the boxes I just need them to stack on top of each other. Another thing I can't figure out is the fact that the headings on my boxes are automatically at the bottom and move up when populated with information, instead of staying fixed at the top of their boxes. I've tried looking at online resources, but couldn't find too much information on this. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: a big part of the problem is `.box-2 { height: 250px; }`. you want to avoid fixed heights like that.

Comment: would I make this a percentage? Thanks for clarifying

Comment: same with the fixed height on `.box`. well, why are you defining a height in the first place? You should let the content in the element define the height. If you need spacing or something, use paddings/margins.

Comment: I tried to define height so that the 3 boxes on the top right would all be next to each other and drop down information from the top down, not bottom up- but that didn't work. How do I fix that?

Comment: If I understand what you're going for, add `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.main-container` and remove the heights from `.box-1` and `.box`

Comment: I'm not using container.... Do I have to attribute all these divs into a container?

Comment: Huh? `<div class="main-container">` is `.main-container`

Comment: Oh I forgot about those- guess I never ended up using them. It ended up working- thanks! Do you know how to have elements responsively stack when resizing the page?

Comment: which elements and what do you mean "responsively stack"?

Comment: There are 6 structured boxes- 4 on the top, 2 on the bottom. What I basically want to do is have these boxes all stack on top of each other when the screen width is too small.

Comment: Don't `float` them or limit their `width`. Make sure they're `display: block` and `width: auto` or `width: 100%` like you've done with `.box` and `.box-2` in one of your media queries.

Comment: But I have to set the width so that they line up next to each other- is there another way to do this? If I leave it in auto they're all bunched up next to each other and everything moves when the calculations pop out